# Where is the 4 bytes of thee IPv4 header?

Tags: networking, ipv4, rfc

In the RFC791 (Internet Protocol Specification) on page 12 said:

> "For example, this size allows a data block of 512 octets **plus 64
> header** octets to fit in a datagram.  **The maximal internet header is 60
> octets, and a typical internet header is 20 octets**, allowing a margin
> for headers of higher level protocols."

I understand why maximal IPv4 header is 60 octets, but I can't understand where is there 4 bytes more of header from this string:

> "plus **64 header octets** to fit in a datagram"

Maybe someone can explain me where this 4 bytes lost/or used?

Comment: You did not highlight the important part: "_For example, this size allows a data block of 512 octets plus 64 header octets to fit in a datagram. The maximal internet header is 60 octets, and a typical internet header is 20 octets, **allowing a margin for headers of higher level protocols**._"

Comment: Thanks, but where can I read about this option more, for understanding how it works? Or could you please explain me?

Comment: TCP uses up to 60 octets for its header options. Se RFC 793.

Comment: @user207421, But TCP it's next level which lived in IP Playload data field, in header only one special filed "Protocol", no additional options.

Answer (score -1):

This RFC was written way back in 1981.  Back then, apparently, this was a typical system block/header size.  Today, virtual all systems support much larger datagrams, and probably block sizes as well (some other experts can address that part, maybe).

--I re-read this.  I see what you are getting at.  I think the answer is in the RFC: "*allowing a margin* for headers of higher level protocols."

If the 60 in "internet header is 60 octets, and a typical internet header is 20 octets" refers to TCP (vs IP) header, then there should be an errata on the RFC.  There is not.

Comment: The IPv4 header has not changed in this respect since 1981. Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Not entirely true.  Options have since been added, e.g. router alert.  Also, interpretation has changed, e.g. DSCP.  Typical MTU sizes have also changed.  I guess I don't see where this is headed--simply an academic Q?

Comment: Yes @Andrew, there is no practical reason right now, just for a deep understanding..